# What is the RGB value of Edison Light Bulbs?

Tags: led, led-strip, light, rgb

I've been doing a little electrical engineering (outside of my lane a bit). I'm trying to get the RGB values for Edison light bulbs. Can anyone provide me with those?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ..... are you talking about color temperature?

Comment: why are you using the `led` and `led-strip` tags?

Comment: How about editing a picture with photoshop and checking RGB there?

Comment: I'm asking for the closest RGB match to the golden glow that an Edison bulb emits so I can use it with my LED light strips and my smart bulbs.

Comment: Photoshop isn't as precise as getting an exact match

Comment: There is no "exact match". Incandescent bulbs produce a continous spectrum governed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law. Those "RGB" values in contrary are completely arbitrary and depend on the pigments used for the color mask of your TFT screen. Or, on the non-continous emission spectrum of the LEDs you use. Each LED type has another one. There's dozens of red types, orange types, yellow types, etc.

Comment: If you want an accurate answer buy a colorometer. They cost as much as a high end DVM. Some offer both RGB and CMYK values.

Comment: If you are trying to do this, you may also find it enlightening to read about color rendering index (CRI)  and color temperature. Lighting is a very complex subject.

Comment: You may also benefit from reading this: http://www.tannerhelland.com/4435/convert-temperature-rgb-algorithm-code/

Comment: @mkeith the problem with that algorithm is it does not factor in CRI.  It would be more accurate to get the CIE x,y chromaticity coordinates from the datasheet and convert the coordinates to RGB.

Comment: @Misunderstood I forsee yet another misguided RGB product with CRI 17 claiming "adjustable CCT". Should be outlawed.

Comment: The appearance has no single RGB value nor CCT but a spectral shape of colours, you want the dominant one ? Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used Firefox Web Developer Eyedropper to grab the RGB from a photo of an Edison Light Bulb.

[image]

#FACA08
(250,202,8)

[image]

---

A lighter pixel
This is very close to the color when a 2700K 97 CRI LED was reflected off bright white paper:  #F4D4AB (244,212,171) just a little less blue.

#F5D483
(245, 212, 131)

[image]

---

I do not believe the LED actually illuminates using the color you see when viewing the filament.  The filament LEDs are no different from other lighting LEDs.  Many of these "Edison Lights" have Color Correlated Temperature (CCT, e.g. 3000K) and Color Rendering Index (CRI, e.g 80).  With that you can get the [CIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Commission_on_Illumination) x,y [chromaticity coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space) based on CCT and CRI.  Both CCT and CRI are needed although CCT only will suffice. Once you have the  x,y chromaticity coordinates they can be translated to RGB.

LED datasheets often have the CIE x,y chromaticity coordinates as shown here:

[image]

Using CIE x,y chromaticity coordinates from the datasheet of a 2700K CRI 90 LED (red x,y).

I wrote an SVG app to plot the x,y on a chromaticity diagram to compare two LEDs.
The red x,y are from a Citi CLU036-1205C1-273H5G3 2700K 90 CRI
The blue x,y are from a Citi CLU036-1205C1-30AL7G4 3000K 70 CRI

I used the eyedropper to grab the RGB off the chromaticity diagram for the 2700K 90 CRI.

#F7AF60
(244,175,90)

[image]

[image]

---

Using CIE x,y chromaticity coordinates from the datasheet of a 2700K CRI and using a [CIE Color Calculator](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?ColorCalculator.html) I get:

#FDAC5A
(253, 172, 90)

[image]

---

**Some various CCT and CRI reflected off high grade bright white paper.**
[image]

#F06F5C  1750K CRI 98
#E2CBAC  3000K CRI 80
#F4D4AB  2700K CRI 97 (244,212,171)
#E96C66  Luxeon Fresh Focus Red Meat

---

2700K is a very warm light.  97 CRI is very close to (natural) sunlight (CRI 100 = sunlight)

> I'm asking for the closest RGB match to the golden glow that an Edison
>   bulb emits

There is no difference between a "Edison Bulb" and any other LED light bulb.
In my opinion a nice warm light is 2700K with a high CRI.

Grabbing the RGB with the eyedropper from the reflection of a 2700K 97 CRI LED off a bright white paper we get this:

**Not a very "golden glow"**
[image]

---

2700K CRI 97
Measured with a StellarNet BLUE-Wave Spectrometer

The PPFD is a measurement of the number of visible photons in µmols.
So this PPFD measurement shows exactly what wavelengths are being emitted (as a plant "sees") before they are adjusted for photopic luminous efficacy (human perception).

**2700K CRI 97 Quantum µmol/m²/s**  (number of photons)
[image]

---

Slightly lower CRI, more green and less red.

**2700K CRI 90 Quantum µmol/m²/s** 
[image]

---

When the number of photons are adjusted for photopic luminous efficacy it is not what most people would expect.   This is exactly the same LED being measured (seconds later) with the same spectrometer as the first image with the measurement units flipped from PPFD to Lux.

**2700K CRI 97 Photometric Lux**
[image]

---

**Examples of Low and High CRI**

[image: Examples of Low and High CRI apples]

[image: Examples of Low and High CRI strawberries]

Comment: Put the RGB values please just for future sake

Comment: This result will be specific to the color balance of the camera that was used to take that photo. It's not some sort of absolute.

Comment: That's a very orange light, probably <1800K. Also you might want to scale it so one of the numbers (the red in this case) is FF(255).

Comment: @Misunderstood, that is not the color of light that the lightbulb produces ..... a closer match would be if you got the color of a white sheet of paper that has been placed a short distance from the bulb

Comment: @jsotola - most camera's with automatic white balance will 'balance' that piece of paper to R=G=B (or in other words, white or grey/gray)

Comment: Btw, isn't this, by definition, the color temperature of the tungsten filament at that temperature?

Comment: Answering myself: yes, it is. https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1999/AlexanderEng.shtml  about 3000k for a tungsten filament. Also (very) helpful: http://planetpixelemporium.com/tutorialpages/light.html . 40W tungsten is about 255, 197, 143 according to them.

Comment: should be 2600K above, not 3000K...

Comment: @RJR CCT alone is not enough.  You need to factor in CRI as well.

Comment: @RJR Almost, it is a few percent off due to not perfect black body radiator.

Comment: @jsotola If the photo looks like what you see with your eyes, why would it not be the right color. The you can choose from various pixel colors.  It's a legitimate method.   The paper reflection did not work very well for me.  I blame that on the iPhone camera.  Using the x,y chromaticity coordinates from the datasheet to calculate the RGB seems to be a good method.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's more yellow than orange.  If the CIE knows what they are doing, it should be more orange than it is.  The CCT is 2700K.

Comment: @Misunderstood, you are right to choose the color the way you did  .... i failed to consider the problem with the camera using the white sheet method

Answer (score 2):

do a visual comparison using something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://planetpixelemporium.com/tutorialpages/light.html) website has some empirical matching of RGB values to apparent filament temperatures. For a 40W incandescent bulb with a color temperature of 2800K, the suggestion is (255,197,143)

Here is what that looks like (there's quite a bit more blue in it that some other answers):

[image]

Here is the table (credit to the above-linked website, above graphic is mine).

[image]

Comment: This is works well enough but it has issues.  The CCT to RGB algorithm often requires red to be 255.  The algorithm floating all over the Internet does not take CRI into consideration.  With red being the major color factor in CRI and red is fixed in this CCT algorithm it ignores the most important R9 color palette.   See "Enter R9": https://medium.com/@yeutterg/r9-more-important-than-cri-468f0efc0d58

Answer (score 1):

RGB value doesn't have units. It depends on the specific monitor and GPU combination and calibration.

To measure color, you can measure its temperature, use colorimeter or compare it to a known calibrated color such as a Pantone swatch.